# Pagerfanta not working by use queryBuilder in Symfony PHP

Tags: symfony, query-builder, pagerfanta

I have queryBuilder and I want to use Pagerfanta

So this is my code

```
$adapter = new DoctrineORMAdapter($queryBuilder);
$pager = new Pagerfanta($adapter);

$pager->setCurrentPage($options['page']);
$pager->setMaxPerPage($options['limit']);

return $pager;
```

but on frontend when I click on next or choose page it will always show on first page.
[image]

I don't know how Pagerfanta working please help.

Answer (score 0):

I've already fixed this.

Because I Pagerfanta don't know what is this page it's still look at default page 
`"$options['page'] == 1"`

So I just send parameters page from url to

```
page = app.request.get('page') 

"$options['page']"
```